# Pointer being freed was not allocated even though it was allocated before

Tags: c++, pointers

I have error that says **error for object 0x7ffbaf002000: pointer being freed was not allocated**. But I have printed out the memory address and it was indeed allocated before at **0x7ffbaf002000** in the function `allocFlights(Flight**, int)` inside the loop when `flight[0] = (Flight*) malloc(sizeof(Flight) * 60)`. So I print out the memory address at `std::cout << flight[0] << std::endl` in function `deAllocFlights(Flight**, int)` to see if it's there and it is there at **0x7ffbaf002000** inside the loop

I don't understand why I have this problem. I'm still new at C++.

Here is the struct Flight:

```
typedef struct {
    int flightNum;
    char origin[20];
    char destination[20];
    Plane *plane;
}Flight;

void getAllFlights(Flight **flight) {
    FILE *file = fopen("reservation.txt", "r");
    int i = 0, totalFlights;

    if(file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error in opening file");
    }

    fscanf(file, "%d\n", &totalFlights);
    *flight = (Flight*) malloc(sizeof(Flight*) * totalFlights);


    allocFlights(flight, totalFlights);  // Allocate here
    .
    .
    .
    deAllocFlights(flight, totalFlights);  // Error: Deallocate here
    fclose(file);
}
```

Function allocFlights

```
void allocFlights(Flight **flight, int totalFlights) {
    for (int i = 0; i < totalFlights; i++) {
        flight[i] = (Flight*) malloc(sizeof(Flight) * 60);
        std::cout << flight[i] << " " << i << std::endl;  // Print out memory address
    }
}
```

Function deallocFlights

```
void deAllocFlights(Flight** flight, int totalFlights) {
    for (int i = 0; i < totalFlights; i++) {
        std::cout << flight[i] << " " << i << std::endl; // Print out memory address
        free (flight[i]);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
int main() {
    Flight *flight;
    getAllFlights(&flight);
    free(flight);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pick one: C or C++. This could simplify many things for you.

Comment: No such language as C/C++. This is C++

Comment: Note that your code is C++ because you use `std::cout << flight[i] << …`.  However, if you're coding in C++, you should not be using `malloc()` and `free()` — you should be using C++'s superior `new` and `delete` operators, if you have to manage memory explicitly at all.

Comment: Note that `perror()` does not exit, so if you fail to open the file, you check and report that you failed (good), but then proceed to use the null file stream, which will not lead to happiness.

Comment: None of this code works if `Flight` is a non-POD type, even if you get the code to compile.  The reason is that you can't use `malloc` or `free` on such types, as you are not constructing objects.  Drop this type of coding and use `std::vector` and other containers that C++ provides (and get yourself a better C++ book / teacher / whatever you're learning C++ from).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right, I shouldn't mixed malloc and free in C++ file. It works when i switch to C file instead

Comment: @tuyenle I know that your current type is `POD`, but as soon as you add (or replace) any type in your `Flight` class to a C++ type, all of that code you wrote (or at least most of it) stops working and you've wasted your time (maybe not -- you've learned not to write code this way).  So you might as well use C++ idioms and not `C` style coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're deallocating your first flight twice. So the second time you deallocate it, the system tells you that it hasn't been allocated because, although it was allocated, it was also deallocated. You don't need to call `free(flight);` at the end because you already deallocated all flights in `deAllocAllFlights()`. As mentioned by David Schwartz in the comments, this is because `flight[0]` is the same as `*flight` (or as he put it `*(flight + 0)`).

Comment: It may help to remind him that `flight[0]` is equivalent to `*(flight+0)` and thus equivalent to `*flight`.

Answer (score 2):

There is missing one star everywhere.

The code works with the original variable as array of pointers to `Flight` (or pointer to pointers to `Flight`). Therefore it has to be defined with double star:

```
int main() {
    Flight **flight;
    getAllFlights(&flight);
    free(flight);
    return 0;
}
```

And the same for every function:

```
void getAllFlights(Flight ***flight) {
    ...
    *flight = (Flight**) malloc(sizeof(Flight*) * totalFlights);

void allocFlights(Flight ***flight, int totalFlights) {
    for (int i = 0; i < totalFlights; i++) {
        // dereference the pointer first and then access array:
        (*flight)[i] = (Flight*) malloc(sizeof(Flight));

void deAllocFlights(Flight*** flight, int totalFlights) {
    for (int i = 0; i < totalFlights; i++) {
        std::cout << (*flight)[i] << " " << i << std::endl; // Print out memory address
        // dereference the pointer first and then access array
        free ((*flight)[i]);
```

The original code accessed directly the pointer to the variable defined in `main` function and used it as an array which meant it went to the address behind the variable for index `1` and even more with higher indices.

Also note, that `flights` is much better name for the variable and all the other parameters as it's actually array. That would make the code more clear and potentially give better chance to avoid mistakes like this.

Comment: We have no idea what `Flight` is.  If it is a non-POD type, none of this code will work properly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : It is POD, the type is defined in the question. But even if it hadn't been, the code would have been working, at least the part presented so far - there is just malloc and free on the memory, no access to the members (which are obviously uninitialized) and things like that.

Comment: `(Flight*) malloc(sizeof(Flight) * 60);`  This wouldn't work if `Flight` were not a POD type.  The code has more stars than Hollywood.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : thanks for this, I missed this part (`*60`), updated the answer. Anyway, apart from the fact that the structure wouldn't be initialized (including the virtual table), it wouldn't really crash as later it's deallocating using `free()`. I'm not saying the way it is written is good, only that it wouldn't cause crash. If he sticks with plain C, the only thing he actually needs to do is to provide a "constructor" and "destructor" functions for the structure.